# Remove quotes and auto-hyperlink when using Explorer's "Copy as path" context menu

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, context-menu

I frequently use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Right-Click and 'Copy as path' context menu.
But when pasting, it results in a quoted version of the file path e.g.

```
"C:\Folder\myFile.txt"
```

After pasting it, it is really annoying having to remove the quotes and then hyperlink it to itself. Anyone aware of an alternate method that removes the quotes and/or hyperlinks to its own location?

Comment: I always navigate to the directory then copy the address bar. (Pasting then creates the hyperlink automatically.) Does that not work for you?

Comment: @kmote I used a directory for simplicity in the example (bad decision on my part - just updated the question), usual case is to link to a file. Tried it and it doesn't hyperlink. This works for browsers for URLs, not for files/folders in MS Explorer.

Comment: I agree with you: it's a pain. One slight shortcut: Do the `Copy as path`, then paste the quoted path, then select the entire thing (either with or without the quotes), then `Ctrl-K`, `Ctrl-V`, `Enter`. This won't eliminate the quotes, but it will make the whole thing a hyperlink, it's fairly painless, and the quotes don't matter.

Comment: ctrl+k then ctrl+v definitely speeds things up. thanks! One note is that you don't have to paste or even select it first, just go to the desired location and ctrl+k, ctrl+v and enter.

Comment: If you paste the copied path in the File Explorer address bar then you get a "Server not found" message. If you create a new folder and paste the path into it then the quotes are invalid (a computer can deal with this scenario and just do the right thing). So the format is not even valid in File Explorer. However, the target of the result is typically in other programs. All dialogs in other programs that I know of e.g. File Open dialogs break when quotes are added. Microsoft should fix this bug because the copied format is not compatible with anything I know of including File Explorer itself.

Comment: [How to Copy as Path Without Quotes and in File URI Format?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/copy-as-path-without-quotes-file-uri-format/)

Answer (score 5):

If you are in a position to install a 3rd party application I can recommend [Path Copy Copy](http://pathcopycopy.codeplex.com/). You can customise the options that display in the right click menu within Explorer to show only the types of links you use most.

Comment: great little addon on... thanks, saves like 5 clicks and 5 seconds every time

Comment: (it's open source : https://github.com/clechasseur/pathcopycopy )

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem now. If you are willing to do some tinkering, Autohotkey is a very nice tool for a variety of problems. I used it in this case to run a script that automatically removes the

> ""

from, for example

> "C:\Folder\myFile.txt"

---

#### Note

*I am on Windows 11 and using AutoHotKey v1.1 (though i don't think it matters if it's v2.0). Windows 11 has a shortcut in file explorer where "CTRL + SHIFT + C" copies the file path of the selected file, but enclosed it in "" Your mileage may vary on different OS but the code can be tweaked accordingly*

---

#### Code

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe explorer.exe                               ; Hotkey only works when File explorer is open
~^+c UP::                                           ; "~" allows native hotkey function to activate
    clipboard := SubStr(Clipboard, 2 , -1)                          ; Saves to clipboard substring of original clipboard removing first and last character
```

---

#### How it works:

If File explorer is open, when "CTRL + SHIFT + C" is pressed, the filepath is copied to clipboard.
The first and last character is then removed.
The new string is then saved to clipboard.

*You will need to download the autohotkey software and set it up for the first time by going to https://www.autohotkey.com/ and then save the above code as an AHK script. The documentation on their website [(here)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Tutorial.htm) shows the steps of running a script (It's a little bit of work but trust me, it's a really cool tool to code simple hotkeys etc. and can be handy for other things in future)*

---

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go to this weblink :
https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/copy-as-path-without-quotes-file-uri-format/

It is for a guy who create a small VB script that is used with a "nircmd tool ".
A good one script where you can copy the path of any file/folder by right click on it  and select the command from the context menu.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1141523)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Copy Path context menu entry that omits the quotes...

[image: Copy Path context menu entry]

You can add it from PowerShell:

```
$key = 'Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Allfilesystemobjects\shell\Copy Path'
New-Item $key |
    New-ItemProperty -Name 'Icon' -Value 'imageres.dll,242' |
    New-ItemProperty -Name 'Position' -Value 'Bottom'
New-Item "$key\Command" |
    New-ItemProperty -Name '(Default)' -Value 'cmd /c echo|set /p=%1|clip'
```

Or pasted into and run from a .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\Copy Path]
"Icon"="imageres.dll,242"
"Position"="Bottom"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\Copy Path\Command]
@="cmd /c echo|set /p=%1|clip"
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Answer (score -1):

for images, mp4's and other filetypes recognized by webbrowser you can drag the files in your browser and then from the browser drag the fileicon/adress from the browser's adres bar to onenote